# Arduino Serial.println is printing two lines

Tags: arduino, println

I am doing some simple arduino projects in an effort to learn some of the basics.

For this project I am trying to print a line sent through the serial monitor.  When I print the line, my leading text prints along with the first character of the user input, and then a new line starts and the leading text prints again along with the rest of the user data.  I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```css
char data[30];

void setup() 
{  
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
 if (Serial.available())
 {  
  //reset the data array
  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(data);  ++i )
  {
   data[i] = (char)0;
  }

  int count = 0;
  
  //collect the message
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    char character = Serial.read();
    data[count] = character;
    count++;
  }

  //Report the received message
  Serial.print("Command received: ");
  Serial.println(data);
  delay(1000);
 }
}
```

When I upload the code to my Arduino Uno, and open the serial monitor, I can type in a string like:  "Test Message"

When I hit enter, I get the following result:

Command received: T

Command received: est Message

When what I was expecting was:

Command received: Test Message

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looks like it works on a message of n characters coming, here is the message, sent in two bursts.  Do you know what the sender is doing?  Is it sending the T and then the rest of the message or is it sending them all together?

Comment: It seems that the problem has to do with the println executing before the text entered into the Serial monitor has been fully transferred to the buffer. My intent is to send messages with Serial.Write(); So I am operating on the assumption that entering text in the Serial monitor is communicating via Serial.Write--is this a bad assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serial.available() doesn't return a boolean it returns how many bytes are in the Arduino's serial buffer. Because you are moving that buffer into a list of 30 chars you should check that the serial buffer is 30 chars long with the condition `Serial.available() > 30`.

This could be causing the code to execute once as soon as the serial buffer has any data, hence it running for the first letter then again realising more has been written to the buffer.

I'd recommend also completely removing your `data` buffer and using the data direct from the serial's buffer. e.g

```
Serial.print("Command received: ");
while (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.print((char)Serial.read());
}
```

**Edit: How to wait until serial data finishes being sent**

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {                 // Serial has started sending
    int lastsize = Serial.available();        // Make a note of the size
    do {  
        lastsize = Serial.available();        // Make a note again so we know if it has changed
        delay(100);                           // Give the sender chance to send more
    } while (Serial.available() != lastsize)  // Has more been received?
}
// Serial has stopped sending
```

Comment: I tried out the your suggestion of Serial.print(Serial.read()); and while that does give me one line, it prints all of the characters as int's.  However, your comment about executing as soon as the buffer has any data got me thinking.  So I put a slight delay at the start of the Void Loop, which made the println work as expected, as long as the delay was long enough for the length of the string.  Is there a way to check whether a Serial.Write operation has completed? So I would be able to once the string has been fully written to the buffer, instead of having to guess on a delay length?

Comment: @Blau If your expected input is fixed size as it was in your code then you can just wait until it is that size. If not, you can wait until there is any data then wait until the size of the serial buffer stops increasing. I will edit my answer with code and to fix the int bug.